# regex to find first occurence

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, regex-greedy

I'm working on redshift & want to write some query which will remove the message inside the brackets of first occurrence only. In redshift there

input : -

```
FR_3000 Error opening file [File_Location].  Operating system error message [The system cannot find the path specified.].
```

output :-

```
FR_3000 Error opening file [].  Operating system error message [The system cannot find the path specified.].
```

I tried below query but couldn't solve the problem..

```
select regexp_replace(description,'\[(.*?)\]','') from emp;
```

Comment: tell us how it cannot solve your problem.  It may be wrong regex, or even wrong table or column name name

Answer (score 1):

The Redshift regular express functions don't have any notion of group capturing, so the solution won't have the purity of pure regex.

As long as you know that the first instance of ']' will always come after the first instance of '[' you can use:

```
select left(description, charindex('[', description)) || substring(description, charindex(']', description)) from emp;
```

If it's possible that you have a stray ']' at the beginning of your string you can use the slightly less efficient:

```
select left(description, charindex('[', description)) || substring(description, REGEXP_INSTR(description, '\]', charindex('[', description))) from emp;
```

What we're doing in these statements is taking everything before the first left bracket, which is at position `charindex('[', description)` and  everything after the first right bracket, which is at position `charindex(']', description)`, and then concatenating them with the `||` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is.  I have no environment to test this in specifically Redshift.  I guess based on your tag, that replacement is too greedy so the result become `FR_3000 Error opening file [].`  ?

One way is to replace

```
^(.*?)\[.*?\](.*)$
```

with

```
\1[]\2
```

Explanation

```
^                   Start of line
 (   )              group 1
  .*?               any number of character, reluctant match 
                    (match at least as possible)
      \[            follow by open square bracket
        .*?         any number of char, reluctant match
           \]       follow by closing square bracket
             (.*)   group 2, of any number of character
                 $  till the end
```

Please tweak the syntax according to redshift.

In case redshift does not even support reluctant quantifier, change the regex to something like:

```
^([^\[]*)\[[^\]]*\](.*)$
```

Test the regex in  https://regex101.com/r/IDEvK3/1